# Как получить реальный ip адрес запроса Symfony 4 + docker

Tags: docker, администрирование, symfony, php-fpm, symfony4

У меня есть проект на докере, стак классический (php-fpm, nginx, postgresql). В качестве фреймворка Symfony 4. Так вот у симфони есть Request из которого можно получить client ip. Получая его на вагранте я получаю реальный ip запроса. Получая его в докере - я получаю какой-то непонятный ip-шник (судя по всему айпишник контейнера). Вопрос как мне в докере получать реальный ip-адрес, а не контейнерный?

Comment: так вы ж напишите (нажав [edit]): 1. что передаёте в опции `-p`. 2. как на этот порт трафик попадает (через какие маршрутизаторы/прокси проходит).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в опции -p чего? докера? Я там не вручную разворачиваюсь, а через docker-compose. По портам там все стандартно 80 для nginx, 9000 для php-fpm, для постгри 5432... Ничего собственно замысловатого.

Как на этот порт трафик попадает... о_О Собственно я затрудняюсь на этот вопрос ответить... Так как это docker-compose и я ничего дополнительно кроме дефолтов не устанавливал ни проксей ничего подобного.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит посмотреть в сторону:

```
network_mode: host
```

Но будьте внимательны, после этого для контейнеры где указана эта опция не будут использовать виртуальные интерфейсы создании автоматически, а интерфейсы хоста, то есть Вашего устройства.